# How to cache/read a json file?

Tags: java, android, json, caching

I'm having problems trying to cache and read a json file, I use the sample from google dev to cache a file, and then I'm trying to read the file using a different function `readCache()`, but I get an error on

> outputStream.read() -> cannot resolve method read().....

can someone explain me what am i doing wrong?

```
private void cacheFile(JSONObject response) {
     JSONObject res  = response;
     String filename = "jsonfile";
     FileOutputStream outputStream;

     try {
         outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         outputStream.write(res.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));
         outputStream.close();
         Log.e(TAG, "Success");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

private void readCache(String filename) {
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.read();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: why should an **output**stream have a "read" method? Do you know **input**streams, like `FileInputStream`. Maybe this is what you want?

Comment: @AKSW i was using the instructions from "https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=es-419#filesInternal"

Comment: and in those instructions they do `fos.write` ... do you see the difference? I mean, isn't this obvious from the name? Outputstream for me sounds like bringing data to some target. Inputstreams getting data from some source. Copy and paste of examples without understanding is no solution or as you can see, lead to issues ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `readCache()` method to

```
private void readCache(String filename) {
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = openFileInput(filename);
        String body = inputStreamToString(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String inputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return result.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution runs without problem, but when I try to see the content of inputStream this is what I see --- java.io.FileInputStream@ff9b581

Comment: @Pedro obviously, it's still a stream. Either load it into a JSON object are convert it to a String. Google is your friend, use search for how to do this

Comment: but what is IOUtils, my system don't recognize that?

Comment: @AKSW Thanks bro, trying to conver that into a json object right now

Comment: @Pedro removed the IOUtils. You can use this natively now.